# Export settings for a sharp logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export, microsoft-word

I want to export a logo which I made in Illustrator (CC 2015) for a customer and import it into Word so it can be used as a standard template for their letters. The logo in Illustrator is created in a 300 ppi document setting. It contains text with a non standard font. I am working on a retina screen MacBook.

My problem is (and I know I'm not the only one) that no matter what I try: the file becomes just terrible after importing it in Word. With 'terrible' I mean: it loses all of it's crisp and smoothness. The lines of the logo but especially the text parts just become totally pixelated and blurry. Presenting it like this to my customer would not be professional in any kind of way.

This is a screenshot of the logo in Illustrator:
[image]

This is how I export it to PNG for example:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The result isn't all that bad actually:

[image]

...but wait and see what happens after I import the PNG into Word:

[image]

[image]

The end result:

[image]

I am aware that it's practically not possible to get the same kind of quality after exporting the file as a PNG or JPEG (or even importing an .AI file directly into Word, I already tried that) since Illustrator is vectors and PNG of JPEG files become pixels. Still like I wrote before; I can't imagine it can't be done in a way resulting in an acceptable logo quality, at least I do believe there are ways to do it better than I am doing it right now :)

I think Word has a built in compression setting which I know can be turned off on a Win machine but as far I as I can see I can't find that option in the Mac version of Word.

What would you recommend I do?

Comment: @Luciano It seems to be the OP is already saving his file as recommended in the suggested duplicate

Comment: @Emilie I'd still recommend the same as the duplicate: save as PNG or WMF, test different sizes of the logo, see what prints better.

Answer (score 0):

I save your image from AI as PDF (Illustrator default) and looks better than the original on Word:

[image]

I don't know the Word standars, but PNG or JPG are not printing file formats. PDF is the best printing format and Word is a text editing program.

Here a reproduction of your logo made on AI, saved as PDF and placed on Word.

[image]

On JPG or PNG formats you see the pixel representation on Word. With PDF the vector file.

Comment: The problem is that not all verisons of word work out with PDF even when they do word does not always operate like it should. For example the full res document does not anti alias well so it still look like crap in word which is what the OP tried to avoid. ALSo there is allways the risk of accidentally letting word rasterize the thing after which everythibg is broken.

Comment: Also note that there is no use in showing us what it looks like when you put the low res logo in word the problem starts when you put the high res one in